# MySQL Data not flushing to disk

Tags: mysql, innodb, query, mysql-8.0, data-loss

Lets start with what I did...
I copied a table via PHPmyadmin operations/ copy table/(temp1) structure and data.  nothing should make any changes to this copy.phpmyadmin shows 1185199 entries
I copy this structure to a new table(temp2). edit structure changing primary to int auto, and CHAR column to CHAR(16).
I then insert into temp2 select from temp1
Start strange part...

phpmyadmin shows 1187015 entries for temp2.
looking at data with phpmyadmin tables match up to pg.47408 temp2 continues to pg.47481
I search ID > 1239186(last id on pg.47408) this gives 7056 results not the 1816 I expected.

questions: Why is the rest of the data not reported?
why are my id's not matching number of entries? nothing has been deleted from main tables.

```
SETUP: 
 Windows 10 pro on 1TB SSD
 MySQL version 8.0.27
 Apache server (handles PHP for intermediate between other machines)
  hardware: i7 4core(8 thread) 24GB Ram 

isolated network.

databases/tables: Innodb for all tables.
   5 main databases
      1 with 4096 tables on 2TB SSD (slowest growing, read the most of mains)
      4 with 1024 tables each on 4 or 8TB HDD(needed least often but most writes)
table structures are the same for all main databases
    4 Bigint columns, 1 CHAR(32), 1 Bigint Autoinc.

   1 work database on 1TB SSD 
     5 tables that get data from files via load
       4 Bigint columns, 1 CHAR(32), 1 CHAR(4), 1 Bigint Autoinc.
     2 tables for synchronization
        1 int autoinc., 7 int 

---------------------
general process now:
  other machines "get work" via PHP script, sync. table is locked read updated unlocked.
machine finishes work- transfers files via network, calls php page which updates sync table again.

 server runs 5 tabs in web browser looping thru pages 1 tab per main database each 
      pg.1  get files to load lock and update sync table
             truncate work table
             load data
     pg.2 loops thru tables using insert select b1,b2,b3,b4,Char(32),null where sort = xxxx
     go back to pg.1
```

Comment: Temp tables have now been there for over 48 hrs and the results are still the same. Would restarting MySQL fix this?

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB tables only show an approximate number of rows.

If, on the other hand, you executed `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;`, say so.